# React list only shows 1 item from loop

Tags: typescript, react-native

Please advice me as my react native page does not loop through all the returned items from the api.

I have checked all i can check but unfortunately, i am unable to find out where the error comes form

I have tested the api with data all seems to be working well
I have also added the styles and json response

json response is

```
"data":["aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa","{\"amount\": \"2000\", \"dataSource\": null, \"showDatePicker\": false, \"thedatetime\": 2020-07-18T10:49:41.479Z, \"title\": \"Gas\"}"]}
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa Object {
  "amount": "2000",
  "dataSource": null,
  "showDatePicker": false,
  "thedatetime": 2020-07-18T10:49:41.479Z,
  "title": "Gas",
}
Unrecognized event: {"type":"client_log","level":"log","data":["aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa","{\"amount\": \"10000\", \"dataSource\": null, \"showDatePicker\": false, \"thedatetime\": 2020-07-18T10:49:41.479Z, \"title\": \"Food\"}"]}
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa Object {
  "amount": "10000",
  "dataSource": null,
  "showDatePicker": false,
  "thedatetime": 2020-07-18T10:49:41.479Z,
  "title": "Food",
}
```

See my code below

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
  FlatList,
  Text,
  View,
  StyleSheet,
  ActivityIndicator
} from "react-native";
import Constants from "expo-constants";


function Item({ title }) {
  return (
    <View style={styles.item}>
      <Text style={styles.title}>{title}</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

class ExpenseList extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isLoading: true,
      dataSource: null
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    return fetch("https://myurl.com/expense/api/get_all.php")
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(responseJson => {
        this.setState({
          isLoading: false,
          dataSource: responseJson.users
        });
      })

      .catch(error => console.log(error));
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.isLoading) {
      return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <ActivityIndicator />
        </View>
      );
    } else {
      let myExpenses = this.state.dataSource.map((val, key) => {
        return (
          <View key={key} style={styles.item}>
            <Text>{val.title}</Text>
            <Text>{val.title}</Text>

          </View>
        );
      });

      return <View style={styles.container}>{myExpenses}</View>;
    }
  }
}
    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    marginTop: Constants.statusBarHeight
  },
  item: {
    backgroundColor: "#f9c2ff",
    padding: 10,
    marginVertical: 4,
    marginHorizontal: 8
  },
  title: {
    fontSize: 16
  }
});

export default ExpenseList;
```

Comment: Can you share the responseJson ?

Comment: post your json response , and the styles

Comment: I have edited the question to inclue both json response and styles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with the json response
no data was being returned